# getting class type in eclipse template

Tags: android, eclipse, templates, code-snippets

I'm learning to make snippets for eclipse. My idea was to make something to make quick findViewByIds, so when you declare a var the snippet gets the type and the name of the var and writes the rest of the code.

If you write

```
Button myButton findView
```

The snippet should get the Class (Button) and the name (myButton) and write:

```
= (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
```

Im doing good but i cant get the Button class. Any help? My code is

```
= ($type)findViewById(R.id.${name:var});
${cursor}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
${type} ${new_name} = (${type})findViewById(R.id.${name});${cursor}
```

Comment: I changed new_name for name and it does more or less what i wanted to! Thank you!